# How to display ng2 -smart table row data in other page after click on the specific row

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I want to display the smart table row data on another page. So whenever the user clicks on the row data its routes to the new page with this particular row data.

Please help on this, I am stuck

Thanks[This is mytable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shb1I.png) in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the ng2-smart-table [documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation), it seems like there is a `userRowSelect` event that this table triggers when the user clicks a row. You can handle that and use the `Router` to redirect to another page.

You can pass the row data using the extras, something like this:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('<path>', { state: data });
```

and you can access the passed data inside your component that handles the route by using the router again

```
const state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state;
```

but please be aware that the `router.getCurrentNavigation` method only returns something if called in the constructor (or to be more precise: before the navigation has ended). If you need access to the state outside of the constructor, you can use `history.state` instead (but this adds another property to whatever data you pass, which is the `navigationId`).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ..can you send me any example for this,?